# get delta from previous row

Tags: python, pandas

I have a solution to this problem but would like some help in efficiency of syntax.  I wrote this in SAS:

```
data lag;
set nflx;
lag_close = lag(close);
delta = (close-lag_close)/lag_close;
drop lag_close;
run;
```

Writing this in python I came up with this:

```
s1 = nflx.iloc[:,1]
s2 = s1.rename('Close2')
nflx2 = pd.concat([nflx,s2],axis=1)
Current = nflx2['Close']
Previous = nflx2['Close2']
Delta = (Current-Previous)/Previous
Delta = Delta.rename('Delta')
nflx3 = pd.concat([nflx2,Delta],axis=1)
```

nflx is a dataset that has two columns, column 0 is date, column 1 is close which is the closing price of the stock.  My goal is to get a column delta which is the change in the current price from the previous price.  Both codes get the same result but I'm hoping for some help in streamlining the python code.
nflx is a pandas DataFrame that was imported from a csv file.

I've seen several topics on similar subjects but nothing that was helping.

Thank You in advance.

Comment: Can you include a, minimal. example of the DataFrame? And the expected final DataFrame? [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

I just saw this answer, I went and tested it and it works great, much better than my original solution.  When I came back to mark it correct the answer was gone.  I appreciate the help.

Here is the answer:

nflx['Delta'] = nflx.Close.pct_change()